# Add a toc entry to each autofunction

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

I would like to add a toc entry to each `.. autofunction:`
Suppose:

```
.. automodule:: foo.bar
   
   .. rubric:: Functions

   .. autosummary::
   
      myfunction
      otherfunction

   .. rubric:: Details
   
.. <- toc entry "myfunction"

   .. autofunction:: myfunction

.. <- toc entry "myfunction"

   .. autofunction:: otherfunction
```

Note:

- I could add headers, but that gives the same 'header' twice, which I would like to avoid.
- Background: I am avoiding `automodule` that does add the toc-entries to enanble a custom layout (all while being automatically generated [see here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/12015)).